# The first index number of the third part of the list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have list which consists of three parts. In the first and third part, all elements are True. In the second part, all elements are False.

I'd like to know the first index of the third part.

For example, `5` is shown after executing the below code. How do I implement `get_first_index_of_third_part` in the below code? I guess I should use `numpy`, can not find how.

```
three_parts_list = [True, True, False, False, False, True, True, True]
ind = get_first_index_of_third_part(three_parts_list)
print(ind)
```

Comment: Can you add your code for `get_first_index_of_third_part` please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say the three parts exist all the time we can use [`np.diff()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) with [`argmax()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) by converting the True & False values to int i.e

```
def gfi_third(x): 
    return (np.diff(x.astype(int)) > 0).argmax() + 1
```

Sample runs :

```
three_parts_list = np.array([True, False, False, False, False, False,True, True])
three_parts_list2 = np.array([True, False, False, False, True, True,True, True])

gfi_third(three_parts_list)
6 

gfi_third(three_parts_list2)
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the list, comparing each element with the previous:

```
def get_first_index_of_third_part(three_parts_list, part=3):
    current_part = 0
    old = None
    for i, el in enumerate(three_parts_list):
        if el != old:
            # New part found
            current_part += 1
        # Stop at the beginning of the correct part
        if current_part == part:
            return i
        # Keep record of previous element
        old = el
```

Here the `part` argument to the `get_first_index_of_third_part` function determines the number of parts and defaults to 3.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by iterating over array

```
def get_first_index_of_third_part(l):
    # assuming the three parts always exists.
    for i in range(1,len(l)):
        if not l[i-1] and l[i]:
            return i
```

Answer (score 0):

check for first instance where the item in list is False, and the next item is True

```
def get_first_index_of_third_part(three_parts_list):
    for i in range(len(three_parts_list)-1):
        if three_parts_list[i] == False and three_parts_list[i+1] == True:
            print(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

An algorithm to find the index of the beginning of the third part would be:

1. Split list into parts
2. Add lengths of first two parts

This can be done using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
parts = itertools.groupby(three_parts_list)
result = sum(len(list(items)) for _, items in itertools.islice(parts, 2))
```